# How to launch Xilinx ISE Web Pack under Ubuntu?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I've downloaded and successfully installed Xilinx ISE Web Pack 14.4 on Ubuntu 12.10 although I'm unable to launch it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well: it's UNIX, so there are multiple ways to do it.

One of them is this

1. Some preparations (needed only once)

   ```
   $ cd .../14.4/ISE_DS
   $ chmod u+x *.csh *.sh
   ```
2. Execute the correct settings script you can find in the root of the installation

   ```
   $ /path_to_the_installation_dir/14.4/ISE_DS/settings64.sh
   ```

   For a none cshell system with 64 bits.
3. Run a Xilinx tool

   ```
   $ /path_to_the_installation_dir/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ise
   $ /path_to_the_installation_dir/14.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/coregen
   $ /path_to_the_installation_dir/14.4/ISE_DS/EDK/bin/lin64/xps
   $ /path_to_the_installation_dir/14.4/ISE_DS/EDK/bin/lin64/xsdk
   ```

If you want a better system I advise you to take a look at the TCL version of the [Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) tool.

How to setup your Unix environment to point to the correct licenses can be found in [installation](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/dt_ise14-4.htm) document of Xilinx.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. :) By the way, I'm stuck with Xilinx since my university uses that. But thanks anyway for your suggestion as well.

Comment: I guess you where talking about the Modules tools I was advocating.  Module is not a replacement of the Xilinx tool.  It's a nice and open tool to setup your environment for different kind of tools/version/projects.